# How does compare work if value1 == value2 is not None in python?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have found that

```
a == b is not None
```

compared `a == b` and if it is True than executed `b is not None`.

```
(a == b) is not None
```

and

```
a == (b is not None)
```

Where can I find more information about such behavior?
It is quite simple, but I expected `True is not None` to be executed

Comment: [6.16 Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in the language reference, [6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like `a < b < c` have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:
>
> ```
> comparison    ::=  or_expr (comp_operator or_expr)*
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
>                    | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```
>
> Comparisons yield boolean values: `True` or `False`.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, *…*, *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, *…*, *opN* are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that `a op1 b op2 c` doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between `a` and `c`, so that, e.g., `x < y > z` is perfectly legal (though perhaps not pretty).

Both `==` and `is not` are comparison operators, so they chain as described above.